# Remove control characters but keep ½ characters etc

Tags: c#, t-sql, encoding, character-encoding, base64

I have a T-SQL stored procedure that returns a flattened list of results by using the 'for xml' command to convert to XML.

I experience a problem occasionally where data from a third party that contains control characters is streamed into one of the varchar fields converted.

I resolved this by base 64 encoding the varchar before performing the conversion:

```
cast(InvalidText as varbinary) as FixedText
```

I then decode this from base 64 in my C# application.

This works great, except when the text includes a symbol such as ½. After decoding these characters, they are shown as �.

I need to display these characters. Is there a way I can solve both problems?

EDIT: I have tried specifying UTF-8 encoding when sending my XML into my C# application. This has not helped.

Here's a simplified example of what's happening:

SQL:

```
select cast('Take ½ of the total' as varbinary) for xml path ('result'), type;
```

Then I pass this encoded string to my C# application.

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var encodedText = "VGFrZSC9IG9mIHRoZSB0b3RhbA=="; // From SQL encoding above

        var decodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
            Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText));

        Console.WriteLine(decodedText);
    }
}
```

Console output: Take � of the total

Manually adding  at the start of the XML document produces the same results.

Comment: You have two different issues with two different solutions 1) Sending/Receiving (streamed) control character.  So for transmission the control characters have to be encoded and decoded. 2) The culture information based on the language  You have characters that are from 0x00 to 0xFF.  Based on the encoding like Windows 1251 some of these characters are mapped to unicode character that are different depending on the encoding.  So the language (or encoding) type must be included in the xml so the viewer can be set properly to the correct language(encoding).

Comment: Cool, so I've solved problem 1. I tried your idea and included the encoding header tag in the XML, but I'm still getting �. I'm using C#'s System.Text.Encoding assembly like:

Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
 Convert.FromBase64String(text));

Comment: Your description is not all clear... As jdweng told you, the encoding of the input string must be known in advance. This might be UTF8, but there many encodings in the wild... it would help if you add an example of valid `base64`, which we can look into in byte level. Best was a short string and the corresponding `base64` string with  some of the characters which you want to remove or keep (according to your question's title).

Comment: You need to use :  Encoding.GetEncoding("Encoding Name").GetString();

Comment: I've updated question to include more info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about your issue, but I think, that you might be digging in the the wrong spot.

SQL-Server knows two kinds of string to work with:

- 1-byte encoding: extended ASCII, where the collation defines all non-plain-latin characters
- 2-byte encoding: UCS-2, which is almost the same as UTF-16
- Just to mention it: Starting with v2019 there are [special collations supporting UTF8](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/12/18/introducing-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-preview/)

As long as you don't mix 1- and 2-byte strings in binary approaches, this works pretty well.

Try this:

```
SELECT 'A½B' AS UsingASCII
      ,CAST('A½B' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS UsingASCIIasBinary
      ,N'A½B' AS UsingUCS2
      ,CAST(N'A½B' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS UsingUCS2asBinary
FOR XML PATH('')
```

returns

```
Text    binary          base64
A½B     0x41BD42        Qb1C    
A½B     0x4100BD004200  QQC9AEIA
```

You can see the HEX codes 41, BD and 42 for the three characters, and the 00 to make it *2-byte UCS2*.

The code points 41 and 42 are "A" and "B", while the code point BD stands for your special character.

### SQL-Server's results are no miracles...

In SQL-Server the `FOR XML` statement will return a native XML, which output format is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` by default. For sure this will not be UTF8.

### Reconvert the base64 from the example above

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<binaryASCII>Qb1C</binaryASCII>
  <binaryUCS2>QQC9AEIA</binaryUCS2>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/binaryASCII)[1]','varbinary(max)')
      ,CAST(@xml.value('(/binaryASCII)[1]','varbinary(max)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ReconvertedFromASCII
      ,@xml.value('(/binaryUCS2)[1]','varbinary(max)')
      ,CAST(@xml.value('(/binaryUCS2)[1]','varbinary(max)')  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) ReconvertedFromUCS2;
```

### Reading base64 in T-SQL needs a little XML-hack:

Your base64 example:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('VGFrZSC9IG9mIHRoZSB0b3RhbA==' AS XML)
                .value('.','varbinary(max)') AS VARCHAR(MAX));
```

My system returns the "half" symbol correctly. This lets me assume, that your standard collation maps another/no character to this code point.

Try to find out your default collation and check the involved columns' collations and [read about `COLLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but this has not helped. I am not decoding the string in SQL. I need to decode the string in C#. Both of your examples still represent the ½ as �.

Comment: @amarsha4, I'm afraid you did not get the ghist... You write in your question, that you create a *flattened list with `FOR XML`*. As long as you keep this within SQL-Server this is either VARRCHAR (extended ASCII) or NVARCHAR (UCS-2). Nothing else... You do not show/tell us, what you are doing with this *flattened list* after its creation. What I wanted to tell you is: Your sample of base64 is 1-byte encoded. This is extended ASCII. My system shows the "half" symbol, while yours does not. That means: Check the collations involved.

Comment: @amarsha4 Would you please try this: `SELECT 'A½B', N'A½B' `. The first is VARCHAR, the second is NVARCHAR (see the leading `N`).

Comment: @amarsha4 Check this to see, how the collation affects character mapping: `SELECT 'A½B' COLLATE Icelandic_CI_AI
      ,'A½B' COLLATE Japanese_CI_AI
      ,'A½B' COLLATE Korean_90_CI_AI`. The last one is missing the "B", why ever...

Comment: Haha sorry - fingers slipped :)

I think maybe you missed my question edit - I show the encoded text being passed to a C# application.

I checked out the collation and determined the encoding from this:

SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', 'CodePage' ) AS [CodePage];

This returned '1252' which I could then use as the encoding when decoding the string in C#:

var decodedText = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(
 Convert.FromBase64String(encodedText));

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @amarsha4, No I did not miss this, I even used your base64 sample from your edit in my answer :-). All what I wanted to tell you was: You are using plain ASCII, where all *extended* characters are taken from a reduced set of characters from a mapping table, the *code page*. I still think, that you are digging in the wrong spot :-) but - at least - you found the right spot to find something else :-)). Happy Coding

Comment: @amarsha4 One more hint: The communication between SQL-Server and C# is - by default - UTF16. That means, that you are doing several implicit casts and encodings: The XML returns UCS2, but you cast it to ASCII. You create your base64 from 1-byte-encoded strings as 1-byte-encoded base64, then you transfer this to C# as UTF16, re-encode the base64 to a byte-array, which you read as 1252. This does not sound *straight forward*... All of this is completely unnecessary, if you use `NVARCHAR()` throughout the whole process.